# Should I use "will" with "tomorrow"?

Tags: modal-verbs, future-time, will-shall

Which of the following are correctly formed?

> Tomorrow I get up at half past six.

or

> Tomorrow I **will** get up at half past six.

Comment: Both look/feel right to me as a native speaker. Now, which one is more correct, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules of thumb only, and hardly to be chiseled in stone:

Use "will" when you wish to express a *goal* or a firm intention.

**I've been oversleeping too much. Tomorrow I will get up at 6AM.**

Use "get up at six" (that is, without *will*) when you wish to tell someone about a planned schedule (or something that happens *regularly*).

**Last week I worked the late-night shift, 11PM-7AM, and was sleeping until 3PM.  But tomorrow I'm back on the day shift and get up at 6AM.**